# Django Rest Framework together with ManyToMany fields with Through

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Training` modell and a `Drill` model that got a ManyToMany relationship between each other. The issue I'm having is that Django by default enforces uniqueness and it is not possible to have duplicate Drills on the same `Training`.

To solve this, I can use the `through=` param when setting the ManyToMany relationship, but this causes a lot of issues with Django Rest Framework.

**Is there any other way of doing it? Do I have to create a `through=` model just to not enforce uniqueness on my M2M Relationship?**

The issues I'm having with DRF is that I'm also required to have a intermediary Serializer for the new Model that was created. This causes issues when I want to send `Drill` data because it validates it and strip all `Drill` data because it's expecting a `TrainingDrill` (The intermediary model) due to the custom serializer required.

This small change really quickly require tons of extra changes. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question regarding through models:**

Through models are typically used to add further information to a many-to-many relationship (e.g. if you needed to add some sort order, or date the relationship was formed, etc. I'm sure you get the idea).

**Don't use through= to achieve uniqueness:**

In regards to going down this route to avoid uniqueness, I don't think that's the correct way of thinking about it. Based on Django's own example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) 
you'll see that you can add the same instances multiple times to a m2m relationship:

```
>>> a2 = Article(headline='NASA uses Python')
>>> a2.save()
>>> a2.publications.add(p1, p2)
>>> a2.publications.add(p3)
Adding a second time is OK:
>>> a2.publications.add(p3)
```

The many-to-many relationship can be cast on either side (usually not both), here's one way of doing it:

```
class Drill(models.Model):
    training = models.ManyToManyField(Training)
    anotherfield = models.CharField('some other field description', max_length = 128)

class Training(models.Model)
    yetAnotherField = models.CharField('yet another field description', max_length = 128)
```

Hope this helps